# Metro Apps on Windows 8 aren't working with static IP behind auth proxy

Tags: proxy, authentication, windows-8, modern-ui

In Windows 8 Professional, Metro Apps and Windows Update do not work with static IP settings behind authenticated proxy server. They work with DHCP on the same proxy settings (we have DHCP for wifi and static IP for LAN, both using the same proxy server).

IE, Chrome and other desktop apps work nicely with both.

Metro apps worked with an auth proxy (DHCP only), when I changed their proxy settings from the "edit group policy" option:
Start → Settings → Edit Group Policy → Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → Network Isolation → Internet Proxy for Apps

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you shouldn't start questions with "Win 8 professional Metro apps". It looks like spam.

Comment: What exactly is `hostels`?

Comment: @Ramhound Hostels=student residential buildings on campus. Irrelevant, I made the question more general. Basically I meant to say that we have to use DHCP in some places and static IP in other places with the same proxy--if it's working with DHCP but not with static, then there's obviously some issue stemming from the static IP.

Comment: Hmm.. static IP also requires you to setup all different settings (Gateway, ...) as well. Are those the same? DNS, WINS, Subnet.. I am having similar problems right now, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configured a loopback proxy using ccproxy [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/49b36903-747c-41ba-9b89-09893df81ba2). Thanks...